# Why result from awk seems not working

Tags: shell, awk

I have a test data file like the following

```
PAT1
3    - first block
4
PAT2
PAT3
7    - second block
PAT4
PAT5
10    - third block
PAT6 
PAT7
12    - forth block
```

If I run the following command line from shell to find the lines between PAT1 and PAT5 including the lines containing the two string, it works just fine from shell prompty.

```
 
awk '/PAT1/, /PAT5/ ' test_file
```

Results are the following:

```
PAT1
3    - first block
4
PAT2
PAT3
7    - second block
PAT4
PAT5
```

But if I want to execute this awk command line in a shell script file, it doesn't work anymore and nothing is in results.txt file.

```
#!/bin/sh

Data="PAT1"             
Data2="PAT2"                                    

echo "$Data, $Data2"
awk '/$Data/, /$Data2/' test_file > results.txt
```

I believe the syntax of awk code is wrong in a shell script. I tried to read the page [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html), but I could not figure it out quickly what is wrong with awk code in my shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk is seeing the literal text `$Data` and `$Data2` rather than the interpolated values.  For this case, you can (probably) just use double quotes:

```
awk "/$Data/,/$Data2/" test_file > results.txt
```

This will fail if either Data or Data2 contain `/`, so you will instead want:

```
awk 'match($0, data), match($0, data2)' data="$Data" data2="$Data2" test_file > results.txt
```

Comment: You are right. Double quote " fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!